Редактор вопроса отображается автором этого вопроса
Обратил внимание, что в списке новых вопросов, редактор сообщения отображается его автором.
Кажется это баг


Для примера
Python: шифрование данных в коде

просто показывает кто изменил вопрос

@Grundy да, но до этого там всегда был тот, кто его задал...

да вроде нет, всегда показывался последний делавший изменения

Есть разные варианты: задан, изменён, ответ дан... и указывается тот, кто сделал это последнее действие. Это вполне естественно, не очень понимаю, что здесь можно расценить как баг.

В списках показывается пользователь, проявивший последнюю активность; в само́м вопросе одновременно отображаются и автор, и редактор. Так было всегда, да

Это скорей раньше был баг, я знаю о чем вы говорите. Когда заходишь(заходил) в "вопросы-новые" писался кто задал, а на главной уже было кто правил последний. Так было, я сама видела. Просто писалось задан тем то... А на главной писалось изменён тем то... в списке вопросов.//я думала почему тут так, а на главной по другому. Просто был вопрос и писалось задан тем то, даже если вопрос был изменён. И поэтому визуально сейчас по другому не привычно

Не баг. Добавил метку.

@aepot, а по моему так неправильно. На "Главная" должно быть видно все действия, а на "Новые вопросы" должен быть виден автор. Логично?

@чистов_n не логично, это можно долго обсуждать. Факт в том, что указанная проблема в вопросе это по факту не баг, и так задумано. Если хочется изменений, можно сходить на MSE и предложить их там с мотивацией, почему сейчас плохо и почему заживём лучше сразу после них.

@чистов_n, если посмотреть со стороны аккуратно сложены вопросы и те кто задал, то да (зашел в вопросы там вопросы и кто их задал, четенько все лежит). А если посмотреть со стороны, что на стековерфлоу нам не важно кто автор вопроса/ответа, то и хранить его данные ни к чему, более интересно кто последний что то делал с этим вопросом...вопрос по сути не привязан к ТС, мы его правим, время идет, сам тс удаляется итд...//но не привычно стало это точно

@aepot Хорошо, понял. Значит так нелогично задумано. :)

@Dev18 почему "стало"? Насколько я помню, она так работает с незапамятных времён.

@αλεχολυτ, нет. Наверно вы не использовали эту страницу, или не обращали внимание. Но слева ссылка на "вопросы" всегда показывала список вопросов и того кто задал вопрос, ДАЖе если вопрос был изменён. Я это точно помню, и думаю тс не задал бы этот вопрос, если это было всегда так. Визуально заметно изменилось

@Dev18 все верно! Задал, потому что изменилось

На MSE тоже завели как баг, поэтому сниму метку [так-задумано] до дальнейших прояснений. А сам вопрос здесь хорошо бы дополнить, чтобы он был более очевиден. Ещё вот можно скрин из интернет архива добавить для сравнения с текущим поведением.

@αλεχολυτ тогда баг это не «редактор отображается автором» (такого нет и никогда не было), а «в новых вопросах иногда отображается редактор вместо автора» (вот это уже действительно недавно изменилось). Видимо, недоумение в комментах выше из-за того, что автор вопроса изначально написал корявую формулировку

Все вернули обратно. Теперь отображается как раньше
